# Setting a checkbox to Visible = False

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba, visible

I'm trying to make a checkbox disappear if a field is empty using the following code:

```
If rstPIANO.RecordCount <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No PIANO Data exists for this date"
    chkPIANO.Enabled = Not (chkPIANO.Enabled)
    chkPIANO.Visible = False
    Else
        chkPIANO.Visible = True
    End If
```

When I try this the msgbox works, then I get run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set? I do initialize the checkbox earlier in the code with

```
Dim chkPIANO As Checkbox
```

Any thoughts on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ...

```vb
Dim chkPIANO As Checkbox
```

You must `Set` it to something.  If the code is running on the form which contains the check box ...

```vb
Set chkPIANO = Me.CheckBoxName
```

But if the name of the check box control is *chkPIANO*, you don't need to declare a variable with the same name.  You should be able to refer to it as ...

```vb
Me.chkPIANO
```

If your code is in a standard module instead of the form's module ...

```vb
Set chkPIANO = Forms!YourFormName!CheckBoxName
```

As basic practice, add `Option Explicit` to the `Declarations` section of your module and then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about.  Use `Option Explicit` in all your code modules.

Comment: I realized that almost immediately after asking the question. Thanks for your help.